# xtk-deps.js file missing?

Tags: xtk

I am ref to https://github.com/xtk/X/wiki/X:DevelopersHeadsUp
I tried Running XTK during development.
I did the following steps
1) Fork XTK on Github to get the latest sources http://github.com/XTK/X 
2) Clone it to your hard drive

But i couldn't find the xtk-deps.js file in the folder.

When i try

./build.py -d

Its complaining that "The command line is too long" and not generating xtk-deps.js file. Can some one help me where i went wrong ?

Comment: Are you trying it on Windows? A similar error was reported on Windows.
We only use Mac and Linux so we can not test Windows.

Comment: Yes i am trying it on Windows 7. What all modifications i need to do to make it work on windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the error comes from the python script builds via a shell command line which is too long for the Windows prompt. The best is using Linux or Mac, or we can give you one and then you'll have to edit it manualy when you add/remove classes but it's not the easiest !